# How to hide Cancel button in date picker in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, datepicker

I have situation where the date picker should not popup with the cancel option. The reason behind is, user has to select the required date from the date picker. Here the date picker bydefault taking today's date so, `Date selected` event will not hit when user open datepicker and clicks `Ok`. If I use `Unfocuss` event it is hitting even when user clicks on cancel too. So, What I am thinking is to hide cancel button as there is no any direct event for `Cancel` or `Ok` for datepicker in xamarin.forms.
Could someone help me with this please .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use CustomRenderer to achieve this effect,find the `Cancel` button,then set its `Visibility` property to `Gone`.like below:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker), typeof(MyDatePicker))]
namespace YourNamepace.Droid
{
   class MyDatePicker:DatePickerRenderer, IOnDateSetListener
   {

      private DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog;
      private Context context;
      private DateTime currently;

      public MyDatePicker(Context context) : base(context)
      {
        this.context = context;
      }


      protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.DatePicker> e)
      {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        currently = DateTime.Now;
        this.Control.Click += Control_Click;

      }

      private void Control_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {

        datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context,this,currently.Year,currently.Month - 1, currently.Day);
        datePickerDialog.Show();
        Android.Widget.Button cancel = datePickerDialog.GetButton((int)DialogButtonType.Negative);
        cancel.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
      }

      public void OnDateSet(Android.Widget.DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)
      {
        DateTime selectedDate = new DateTime(year, month + 1, dayOfMonth);
        currently = selectedDate;
        Control.Text = selectedDate.ToShortDateString();
      }

 }
```

Comment: Thank you @Leo Zhu - MSFT , I have added this renderer but I am getting two date pickers. One with cancel option and another without cancel options.

Comment: `<DatePicker Grid.Column="1" IsVisible="False" x:Name="FromDatePicker" Format="dd-MM-yyyy" FontSize="Small" Unfocused="From_DateSelected" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>`  This is how I am declaring control on my xaml. Could you let me know where I am doing wrong please.

Comment: @user10594374 try to just use it like   `<DatePicker x:Name="FromDatePicker" > </DatePicker>` to see if it still display two pickers.It works well on my side.

Comment: Awesome @Leo Zhu - MSFT , its working. Thank you so much :)